# How can I execute an oracle procedure with ojdbc-10.1.jar from windows env

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am trying to execute a procedure from Windows env with oracle driver ojdbc-10.1.jar, the procedure is getting executed, but getting the wrong data, whereas the same code and same driver in Linux env is able to execute the procedure and gets the correct data. if I change the driver in the windows env I am getting the correct data. But the problem is I cannot use that driver in my application due to some reasons.

Can anyone clarify me. Why is that behaving like that?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [help](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter) where you will find how to ask questions. Please next time don't include the signature in the post as each post has logo automatically appended to its bottom so that everyone knows who is the author of the post. Thanks :-)

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev If could more details about your procedure code, parhaps code snippet and details about your drivers, it would help others to find the problem.